# Running Spark 2 on HDP 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm running a Spark 1.6.1 on HDP 2.4 and I'm wondering if we can run a Spark 2 driver on a Yarn HDP 2.4 Cluster ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you must use the assembly jar (a big 180Mo jar) provided by Horton itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can run SPARK 2.0 but it will be not supported built by HDP platform. Because by now the SPARK 2.0 included in HDP 2.5 as technical preview. For further information you can check official [documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_release-notes/content/tech_previews.html).